# Node dynamic routing when route is undefined

Tags: node.js

I am new with node and am trying to figure out dynamic routing. I have routes already set up such as

```
app.route('/users')
    .get(dbController.collect)
    .post(dbController.insert);

  app.route('/users/:userId')
    .get(dbController.read)
    .put(dbController.update)
    .delete(dbController.delete);
```

I want to be able to do something similar for routes that I have not defined in my code while still letting the routes I have defined work as usual. For example if someone was to send a get request to https://example.com/books/12 it would dynamically run the read function as it does for users.

Comment: I don't think if that's possible. You'll have to mention endpoints and handlers explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Express routing allows you to do catch-all routes:

```
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Route is unknown')
  // Do something here...
})
```